# How can I check MySQL engine type for a specific database?

Tags: mysql

How can I check MySQL engine type for a specific database via mysql query?

Comment: Via what? MySQL query, JDBC, ODBC...?

Comment: Databases don't have an engine type, only tables do. The server will have a *default* engine type for new tables, but that is set in the configuration, start up switches, or on a per-session (*not* per-database) basis.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In MySQL, databases don't *have* an engine type; *tables* have engine types. [The Friendly Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-engines.html) even explicitly states:

> It is important to remember that you are not restricted to using the same storage engine for an entire server or schema: you can use a different storage engine for each table in your schema.

You can query the `information_schema` database (substitute your database name and table name in the example):

```
SELECT `ENGINE` FROM `information_schema`.`TABLES`
  WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='your_database_name' AND `TABLE_NAME`='your_table_name';
```

You can also get the value of the global environment variable `storage_engine` - which is only used as a default when a table is created without an engine specified, it does not affect the server in any other way:

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'storage_engine'
```

Comment: I am not asking for tables :-(

Comment: @joe: You can't read what does not exist :-( Engine types only exist for individual tables.

Answer (score 16):

Databases do not have engines. Tables have. You can run e.g. [SHOW TABLE STATUS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-table-status.html):

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM mydatabase
```

Available engines can be found with [SHOW ENGINES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-engines.html).

---

Tip: if you are the using the official command-line client rather than GUI tools you might want to use the [`\G` command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-commands.html) (not to be confused with lowercase `\g`):

> Send the current statement to the server to be executed and display the result using vertical format.

... which turns this:

```
mysql> SHOW TABLE STATUS;
+----------------------------------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+-----------
---+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+-----
------------------------------------------------------+
| Name                             | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_leng
th | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time | Check_time | Collation         | Checksum | Create_options | Comm
ent                                                   |
+----------------------------------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+-----------
---+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+-----
------------------------------------------------------+
| canal                            | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |    0 |              0 |       16384 |               0 |
 0 |  27262976 |              1 | 2015-04-10 11:07:01 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_general_ci   |     NULL |                |
```

… into this:

```
mysql> SHOW TABLE STATUS\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           Name: canal
         Engine: InnoDB
        Version: 10
     Row_format: Compact
           Rows: 0
 Avg_row_length: 0
    Data_length: 16384
Max_data_length: 0
   Index_length: 0
      Data_free: 27262976
 Auto_increment: 1
    Create_time: 2015-04-10 11:07:01
    Update_time: NULL
     Check_time: NULL
      Collation: utf8_general_ci
       Checksum: NULL
 Create_options:
        Comment:
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           Name: cliente
         Engine: InnoDB
[…]
```

Comment: It's a verbose output, and for this reason I prefer @Piskvor's answer. (Simply a matter of preference.)

Comment: @Tass Personal preference apart, `SHOW` commands are useful when you have a pre 5.0 server (happily rare nowadays) or your user has not been granted permissions to read `information_schema` (can happen on some shared hosting services).

Comment: I do agree, it's very useful. I did append `\G` to `SHOW TABLE STATUS` and the output is much more readable. I have 54 tables, so `SHOW TABLE STATUS` itself is a bit garbled.

Answer (score 4):

`SHOW TABLE STATUS` retrieves that kind of stuff, see the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-table-status.html).

Comment: There's no real way to guarantee that the whole DB is using only one engine. IF you're sure, you can just take the first entry from that database & assume that's the engine you need...

Comment: @joe -- I think you're not understanding at all. Engines are defined at the table level, not at the database level. These fine people have answered your question as best they're able.

Answer (score 2):

Use this command:

```
SHOW ENGINES\G;
```

Your default engine will show as **Support: DEFAULT**

Answer (score 1):

the list of engines used by databases:

SELECT `TABLE_SCHEMA`, `ENGINE` FROM `information_schema`.`TABLES`
group by `TABLE_SCHEMA`, `ENGINE`
order by `TABLE_SCHEMA`, `ENGINE`;